# Non-resolvable import POM Could not find artifact in nexus

Tags: maven, jenkins, openshift, jenkins-pipeline, nexus

This is the error I am facing while doing a Jenkins build by pulling a maven project from Gogs. I am also using Nexus repository. Jenkins, Nexus and others all are running as Docker containers.

```
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-bom:pom:2.0.0 in nexus (http://nexus:8081/repository/maven-all-public/) @ org.jboss.bom.eap:jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools:[unknown-version], /home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/jboss/bom/eap/jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools/6.4.0.GA/jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools-6.4.0.GA.pom, line 55, column 25

[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom:pom:1.1.0.Final in nexus (http://nexus:8081/repository/maven-all-public/) @ org.jboss.bom.eap:jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools:[unknown-version], /home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/jboss/bom/eap/jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools/6.4.0.GA/jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools-6.4.0.GA.pom, line 64, column 25

[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact org.jboss.arquillian.extension:arquillian-drone-bom:pom:1.1.1.Final in nexus (http://nexus:8081/repository/maven-all-public/) @ org.jboss.bom.eap:jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools:[unknown-version], /home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/jboss/bom/eap/jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools/6.4.0.GA/jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools-6.4.0.GA.pom, line 74, column 25

[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar is missing. @ line 87, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar is missing. @ line 94, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs:jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec:jar is missing. @ line 101, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb:jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec:jar is missing. @ line 114, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for junit:junit:jar is missing. @ line 121, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:jar is missing. @ line 127, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.arquillian.protocol:arquillian-protocol-servlet:jar is missing. @ line 133, column 21
```

I am working on [Openshift CD Demo](https://github.com/OpenShiftDemos/openshift-cd-demo), which uses this [Openshift Tasks repo code](https://github.com/OpenShiftDemos/openshift-tasks/tree/eap-7) for building.

Below is error image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error message says

```
Could not find artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-bom:pom:2.0.0 in nexus (http://nexus:8081/repository/maven-all-public/)
```

which means that the mentioned artifact is probably not present in the said Nexus repository.

Comment: So should I add this manually to Nexus? There is no option to upload, I tried cURL (`curl -v -u deployment:deployment123 --upload-file shrinkwrap-resolver-bom-2.0.0.pom.xml http://nexus-cicd-developer.192.168.99.100.nip.io/#browse/browse/assets:maven-all-public`) to upload, it says  HTTP/1.1 405 HTTP method PUT is not supported by this URL

Comment: Use maven to upload file in nexus, using maven POM nexus addin you will be able to upload artifacts in nexus

Comment: Ok, I will try that, But I have a doubt. If you see the error image, it downloaded first 4 jars/poms. Then why is it failing with the shrinkwrap-resolver-bom-2.0.0.pom? I am new to nexus & trying to understand it.

Comment: @JohnSeen Actually, I would try to find the Nexus repository (on the net) which contains the right artifacts and either add it to the settings.xml or proxy it in the company nexus.

Comment: Jboss artifacts can be found here:  https://repository.jboss.org/   ... add a proxy repository to that into Nexus.